# Send data vi ajax to dropdownlist is not completly set as selected

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I send via ajax an ID to get a specific name (label) with his code, which i will show as selected value in my dropdown list in a Bootstrap Modal Form.

I get the code inside the value quotes, but not the label between the option tag like :

```
<option value="123" id="code" selected> </option>
```

But i want to get this :

```
<option value="75000" id="code" selected>Paris</option>
```

Here is my code:

```
<select class="form-select mb-3" id="label" name="label" required>

   <option value="" id="code" selected></option>

<?php  while ($row = $stmtGetLabel->fetch()) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['code'] ?>"><?php echo $row['label'] ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
                                        
...

$(document).on('click', '.update , #act', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url:"inc/functions/ActRef.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{id:id},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#mymodal').modal('show');
            $('#label').val(data.label);
            $('#code').val(data.code);
            $('#id').val(id);
            $('#action').val("EDIT");
            $('#operation').val("edition");
        }
    })
});
```

Whats works wrong with my code ?

any ideas pls?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to set the info on this portion of the HTML:

```
<option value="" id="code" selected></option>
```

Assuming I understand correctly, what you need to do is:

```
$('#code').attr('value', data.code).html(data.label);
$('#label').val(data.code);
```

Comment: Hello @dave, Thank you very much, yeah it works, but i can see that only in in inspected elements that he set the value as selected : <option value="75000" id="cr_dex" selected="">PARIS</option>. On the HTML page the field is blank of  the selected value !!